# How do I attach the coordinates of a sprite to its center? LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite

I want that when I set a sprite to certain coordinates, it is set to these coordinates by its center.

[image: For clarity I drew the picture]

Comment: Somewhere in your code, subtract half the width and half the height of the sprite from the center coordinate to get the upper-left coordinate.  Add the halves to the upper-left coordinate to get the center coordinate.

Comment: What class of `Sprite` are you using? Because I'm pretty sure libgdx `Sprite` origin is at `bottom-left` not `top-left`

Comment: Whether this is a permanent subtraction from the coordinates of the sprite very costly operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Sprite.setCenter(x,y)`

> Sets the position so that the sprite is centered on (x, y)

There's no `Sprite.getCenterX()` or `Sprite.getCenterY()` tho. If you need this you can create a class that extends `Sprite` and implement it your self...

```
public class MySprite extends Sprite {
    public MySprite(Texture texture) {
        super(texture);
    }

    public float getCenterX(){
        return getX()+getWidth()/2;
    }

    public float getCenterY(){
        return getY()+getHeight()/2;
    }
}
```

And now use `MySprite`.

You could also override all position related methods

```
public class MySprite extends Sprite {
    public MySprite(Texture texture) {
        super(texture);
    }

    @Override
    public void setX(float x) {
        super.setX(x-getWidth()/2);
    }

    @Override
    public void setY(float y) {
        super.setY(y-getHeight()/2);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPosition(float x, float y) {
        super.setPosition(x-getWidth()/2, y-getHeight()/2);
    }

    @Override
    public float getX() {
        return super.getX()+getWidth()/2;
    }

    @Override
    public float getY() {
        return super.getY()+getHeight()/2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Your method is exactly what I first thought of. But whether this is a permanent subtraction from the coordinates of the sprite very costly operation? Is there anything in LibGDX that would change the rendering of the sprite on the hardware level so that you don't have to constantly subtract or add anything to the sprite coordinates? Maybe I'm exaggerating, and this is not a costly operation at all.